# Explorer Preview Pane locking files

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, windows-registry

im looking into an annoying issue with the explorer preview pane. We are using Windows 8.1, server 08 R2 upstairs. To my understanding, when viewing a file with the preview pane it opens an instance of the file on the server, then locking the file 'in use' if a user tries to delete it etc.

I have found the below reg values that apparently fix it, but i cant find out if anyone has tested it in 8.1. the MS article only says it applies to Win7 / Vista.

The only other suggested 'fix' i can find from MS is to turn off preview pane... i am yet to work out how that is a fix. :(

Can anyone confirm the below for 8.1, or is there another solution?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{993BE281-6695-4BA5-8A2A-7AACBFAAB69E}]
@="Microsoft Office Metadata Handler"
"EnableShareDenyNone"=dword:00000001
"NoOpLock"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{993BE281-6695-4BA5-8A2A-7AACBFAAB69E}]
@="Microsoft Office Metadata Handler"
"EnableShareDenyNone"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this 3rd party app that does the trick, free too. https://app.box.com/shared/7zz5xcy048

Comment: -1 for not giving source. Linking to a box.com link is IMHO bad security practice. I did find the source: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/05/09/foxit-pdf-preview-handler.aspx but I'm not sure it's meant to solve original problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, as above, i have applied both values to my local machine which has had no effect. I still cannot find a way to resolve the issue, but as a workaround i have asked users to pin the preview pane button their ribbon and turn it on/off when required. Takes a few seconds to unlock the file from the server before it can be deleted, but it is better than nothing